# What is the sum of this infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

So the question is -

$\displaystyle S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{10^n}\left(\begin{matrix}2n\\ n\end{matrix}\right)}$. Find $S$.

I tried converting the $n^{th}$ term as a difference of two terms but that didn't worked quite well. I am clueless and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Hint: Recall the Taylor expansion at $x=0$ of $$\sqrt{1-x}.$$

Comment: I am in class 11. We have not been taught the Taylor expansion yet(Hearing the name for the first time) Can you just briefly explain it here. Thanks

Comment: These specifics should have been mentioned in the question. For an amplification of my hint, see an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the OGF of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) we have that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}z^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}} \tag{1}$$
for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|<\frac{1}{4}$. By substituting $z=\frac{1}{10}$:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{10^n}=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4/10}}=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{15}-3}{3}}.\tag{2}$$

---

As an alternative approach, we can prove through integration by parts that:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2n}\theta\,d\theta = \frac{\pi}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}, \tag{3}$$
hence:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{10^n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\frac{2}{5}\sin^2\theta}{1-\frac{2}{5}\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{4}{5\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^2}{(1+t^2)\left(1+\frac{3}{5}t^2\right)}\,dt.\tag{4} $$
Now, by partial fraction decomposition, the last integral equals:
$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+\frac{3}{5}t^2}-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}=-1+\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}\tag{5}$$
as wanted. The same chain of identities can be used to prove $(1)$.

Comment: he is in class 11, so good luck explaining how did you get the first relation!

Comment: @Elaqqad: I bet the OP is able to read the linked Wikipedia page. Anyway, I have just added an alternative approach.

Comment: **To the O.P.** : The first identity is based on the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), and the latter on [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).